# Time Complexity Analysis Dependent nested loop

Tags: time, complexity-theory

I am having a lot of trouble understanding time complexity for nested loops. I have searched for weeks for resources online/books/etc. But I just can not understand how a nested dependent loop works. Take this one for example

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) //n is even //n + 1
    for (int j=i; j<n/2; j++) //(n/2 + 3)*n/4 + n/2 = n2/8+5n/4
        cout << i << “,” << j <<endl; //(n/2 + 1)*n/4 = n2/8 + n/4
```

The time complexity is in the comments, but I don't understand how it arrived at that answer. I understand the n+1, in the first loops; it runs n times plus the fail case. But from there on I don't understand. If someone can explain it to me clearly I would appreciate it.

I have also tried writing it out with an n value but I don't understand what to do with the trace to arrive at that complexity.

Comment: Are you looking for 'Big O' notation (the double loop is O(N*N)), or at a more detailed level.  Note that the inner loop doesn't execute at all for values  of i from (n+3)/2 to n-1 because j is already bigger than n/2.

Comment: The more detailed level, basically what is commented is the time complexity for each line, I am trying to figure out how I get those.

Answer (score 0):

The number of iterations of the second loop can be computed using sum of arithmetic progression. Let's observe how many iterations it does when `i` is iterated:

- When i is 0 it performs n/2 iterations(j = 0, 1, .... n/2 - 1)
- When i is 1 it performs n/2 - 1 iterations(j = 1, .... n/2 - 1)
- When i is n/2 - 1 it performs 1 iteration(j = n/2 - 1)
- When i >= n/2 it performs 0 iterations

And so overall the number of iterations is: n/2 + (n/2 - 1) + ... + 1 = ((n/2 + 1) * (n / 2)) / 2 = (n/2 + 1) * (n / 4)  - Here I am using the formula for sum of arithmetic progression. This is precisely the value you mention(although represented in a bit different way).

As for the outer value - (n/2 + 3)*n/4 + n/2 = n2/8+5n/4 - for each value of `i`, the cycle will perform one more operation - to verify that `j` is more than the limit `n / 2`. Thus you have to sum ((n / 2 + 1) + (n / 2) + .... + 2)  + 1 * (n / 2) - the first sum is for the elements not greater than n / 2 - 1 and the second is for the remaining ones that immediately fail the check  j